# C++ Linux Bind Socket with char[14]

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm really new to C++, so this question can absolutely be stupid.

On the linux documentation for socket programming, i found this:

> ```
>  struct sockaddr {
>        a_family_t sa_family;
>        char       sa_data[14];
>
>  };
> ```

But, when I write `sockaddr address = {AF_INET, strAddress};`
GCC returns me error:

> array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

And what I don't understand is that if I write

```
sockaddr address = {AF_INET, "AN_AARRAY_OF_CHAR"};
```

, it works and doesn't return an error.

So,
what is  the difference between `"THIS ARRAY"`, and `char test[]="THIS ARRAY"`?

And how can I resolve the error it returns me?

Comment: Interestingly enough, what you are fighting with is because you're dealing with a C API and C doesn't support inheritance without hacks. `sockaddr` is an abstraction. It's a base  class of sorts for a number of different types of socket connections. You aren't expected to directly use `sockaddr`; instead you use a brute-force C "derived class", like a `sockaddr_in`, and cast a pointer to that "derived class" to a `sockaddr *`. If you want an end-to-end C++ experience, [may I recommend Boost ASIO](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)?

Comment: Other handy reading: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html). [9.24. `struct sockaddr` and pals](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/sockaddr_inman.html) should be particularly helpful here.

Comment: C/C++ does not support array assignment. When you do `sockaddr address = {AF_INET, strAddress};`, you are essentially assign the sa_data member to another array, which would not work. You can initialize the members separately: `sockaddr address = {AF_INET}; std::copy(std::begin(strAddress), std::end(strAddress), address.sa_data);` (given strAddress is also the type of char[14], although in this case, `sockaddress_in` should be used)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sockaddr` is a generic descriptor for any kind of socket operation. `char sa_data[14]` is just a placeholder for family-specific data.  You are not supposed to use `sockaddr` directly at all.

Each socket address family has its own specific `sockaddr_...` struct type.

For the `AF_INET` address family, you must use `sockaddr_in`, a struct specific to IPv4-based communication.

For the `AF_INET6` address family, you must use `sockaddr_in6`, a struct specific to IPv6-based communication.

And so on.

You must use the appropriate `sockaddr_...` struct for the address family you are working with, and cast its address to `sockaddr*` when passing it to a socket function that takes a generic `sockaddr*` parameter.